# Alerting on Database Mirroring Events

Tags: sql-server-2008, mirroring

I am looking for the actions one must take to cause Threshold Alerts to occur for a single mirrored database on an instance of SQL Server 2008 containing multiple mirrored databases.

FYI: This is already posted on [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/251551/sql-server-2008-mirroring-threshold-alerts-at-database-level) and submitted as a bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/657230/alerting-on-database-mirroring-events).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joe Sack's answer on ServerFault is as good as it gets:

https://serverfault.com/questions/251551/sql-server-2008-mirroring-threshold-alerts-at-database-level/251989#251989

For some background, Joe runs the Microsoft Certified Master of SQL Server program.  He knows his stuff.  (I can vouch for him personally.)

Comment: Thank you Brent. I do hope that the Microsoft Connect team addresses this issue in a future update.

Comment: Update from Microsoft

"... the underlined issue was identified as a core Engine issue ... will not be classified as a hotfix required for the SQL 2008 or SQL 2008 R2. We will try to address this issue in our current release for SQL 2011 ... the risk for breaking existing functionality by changing the output format (the message format) is fairly high. We decided therefore that we cannot make this change ... workaround is to create your own alert that includes the complete message. See also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966392.aspx"